# Correct way to join on 3 Tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to pull data from 3 different tables and my result set is not what I'm expecting.

```
SELECT mdp.ReportDate
    , mdp.PolicyNumber
    , Company
    , StateCode
    , LOB
    , mdp.AccountReference
    , EffectiveDate
    , EquityDate
    , AccountBalance
    , TermPremium
    , DelinquentAmount
    , PolicyStatus
    , dcbpt.PolicyTermExtendedData
    , TermsInDays
    , dcba.AccountId
FROM Bil_MonthlyDelinquentPayments mdp
    INNER JOIN DC_BIL_Account AS dcba
        ON PolicyNumber = dcba.AccountReference
            AND ReportDate = (
                SELECT Max(ReportDate)
                FROM Bil_MonthlyDelinquentPayments maxmdp
                WHERE Year(maxmdp.ReportDate) = 2017
                    AND Month(maxmdp.ReportDate) = 01
                )
    LEFT JOIN DC_BIL_PolicyTerm AS dcbpt
        ON dcba.AccountId = dcbpt.PrimaryAccountId
            AND PolicyTermEffectiveDate = (
                SELECT Max(PolicyTermEffectiveDate)
                FROM DC_BIL_PolicyTerm
                )
ORDER BY AccountId
```

In my result set the column dcbpt.PolicyTermExtendedData is being returned as a null value. This column contains data in the table and I would expect my result set to contain that data but it doesn't.

Comment: How can we know the correct query if you dont provide enough information?       Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: does your value in the table DC_BTL_PolicyTerm satisfies condition "and PolicyTermEffectiveDate =
       (SELECT Max(PolicyTermEffectiveDate) 
           FROM DC_BIL_PolicyTerm)" ???

Comment: Do you understand how [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm) works?

Comment: And please alias all of the fields in your query, we have no idea what table they came from. Your query would fail code review here for not doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That null value is from the second table used in your left join. Left join will return all the results from the 1st table (on the left) and if it does not find a match in your 2nd table to join on, it will pair the first table with a null value. Take a look at what you ware matching on.

Comment: thank you for the feedback this makes perfect sense.